# MongoDB find all dictionary in array of a document

Tags: mongodb

```
{
    "name": "sample_config222",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Bluth",
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "first_name": "Janet",
            "last_name": "Bluth",
        },
    ]
}
```

I want find all dictionaries that matches `key: value` in a document. Here is the two things,

1. Find the document with `"name": "sample_config222"`
2. Search dictionaries in array of document that we selected in `1`.

I tried

```
db.config.find({name: "sample_config"}, {"data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } })
```

It is showing only one dictionary which is the first one

```
{
    "name": "sample_config222",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "first_name": "George",
            "last_name": "Bluth",
        }
}
```

And also it is getting results from other document contains `"last_name": "Bluth"`

I tried with `$and` which is showing entire document.

**UPDATE:**

There is similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection) which uses `$elematch` returns only one dictionary in array. But i want get all dicts whichever matches the query

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you provided,

```
db.config.find({name: "sample_config"}, {"data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } })
```

Breaks down to this

1. Find all documents where the name is sample_config
2. Project only fields where `data.last_name` is equal to `Bluth`.

The key here is that the `find` method takes multiple parameters.

```
function (query, fields, limit, skip, batchSize, options)
```

These can be found by executing a `find` command on the shell without parentheses. This works for all shell commands, and can be quite useful if you forget how to use a command.

```
db.config.find
```

To get the result you want, you need to change the query to this:

```
{name: "sample_config", "data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } }
```

Note that I removed the `}` after `"sample_config"` and removed the `{` before `"data"`, making it a single query document for the `find` command instead of a `query` and `project` document.

*UPDATE:*

I realize you *also* want to project the resulting documents do the array field only contains the matching elements. Now we just need to combine your original projection with the new query

```
db.col.find({name: "sample_config", "data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } }, {"data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } })
```

This will return documents of the form

```
{
    _id: xxx,
    data: [
       { id: xxx, first_name: xxx, last_name: "Bluth" }
    ]
}
```

However, according to [the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/), this will only return the *first* matching array element, not *all* matching elements.

If you need to further project down the data, I would suggest using the aggregation framework, as those operators are more robust.

That could look something like

```
db.col2.aggregate({$match: {name: "sample_config", "data": { $elemMatch: { "last_name": "Bluth" } } }},{$unwind:"$data"},{$match:{"data.last_name": "Bluth"}},{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$data"}})
```

Which results in the following output

```
{ "id" : 1, "first_name" : "George", "last_name" : "Bluth" }
{ "id" : 2, "first_name" : "Janet", "last_name" : "Bluth" }
{ "id" : 2, "first_name" : "Janet", "last_name" : "Bluth" }
```

From these original documents

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c5b025fea781cb935c975ae"), "name" : "sample_config", "data" : [ { "id" : 1, "first_name" : "George", "last_name" : "Bluth" }, { "id" : 2, "first_name" : "Janet", "last_name" : "Bluth" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c5b0283ea781cb935c975af"), "name" : "sample_config", "data" : [ { "id" : 1, "first_name" : "George", "last_name" : "Dole" }, { "id" : 2, "first_name" : "Janet", "last_name" : "Bluth" } ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c5b028bea781cb935c975b0"), "name" : "sample_config", "data" : [ { "id" : 1, "first_name" : "George", "last_name" : "Dole" }, { "id" : 2, "first_name" : "Janet", "last_name" : "Johnson" } ] }
```

You can find the docs on these operators here:

- [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/)
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That didnt work for me. It is retrieving all the dicts in array of document

Comment: In the Update, the second query is working fine. not sure about first  one which i'm getting only one dict? Is there any way to stop limiting the results or any options like?

Comment: I'm still not entirely clear what you're doing with the data, but the aggregation framework is going to be the most flexible option for you. Will that work for you?

Comment: Yes, looks good. Thanks for the help :-) But the first one is bugging me like why is it resulting one dict. Is there any limit when we use `elematch`. I'm new to Nosql & mongo. Dont know about query planning/projection in it.

Comment: It was hiding from me [in the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) the whole time. "Both the $ operator and the $elemMatch operator project the first matching element from an array based on a condition."